# Is it possible to send email programmatically, without storing it in the Sent items?

Tags: ios, email

I have an app which sends out email, with attachments containing certain amount of sensitive data.(using the MFMailcomposer stuff.. which uses the native mail functions).. As a result, the sent mail is stored in the mail's sent items.

Is it possible to send the mail, without it getting stored in the sent box? Is it possible to delete the last sent mail? Any way to ensure that it's deleted programmaticaly, once mailed?

PS: I don't prefer to encrypt the mail since the data is not very sensitive but just to meet the Compliance requirement of not having it stored in any form..

Comment: FWIW the email needs to go through an email server which may/will have different retention requirements then you might want.

Comment: Email goes through many servers from the sender to the recipient. Worrying about just one possible storage location of the email is kind of pointless. If the email has sensitive info then you should properly encrypt the email so it is safe all the way through.

Comment: Also, email is sent in plain text so all of its contents can be sniffed.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm not worried about the mail servers, My concern is about leaving it accessible on the end-user's mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is acceptable for your case but I suppose you could post the information to a web service and have that forward it along. [PHP's mail function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) comes to mind. That way it's never stored in the user's personal email.

That might be a roundabout way of accomplishing what you want but it *would* work.

Comment: I'm making use of the native mail controllers since I don't have a web-based infrastructure.

Comment: Also, is not an answer to the question but just an alternative approach.

Comment: Ah, sorry this won't help you out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, and this is a terrible user experience. Compliance requirements be damned! Everything related to mail, other than the small portion of compose view controller presentation, is private API, and for good reason. If you are able to access the sent items, you would be able to access the inbox, and so on. Do you want software on your device to have such access? Also, deleting a mail without the user consent is a very short road to removing the app from their device. Even if this is a BYOD enterprise app, once you start doing things that are not apparent, you lose your customers.

If you have stricter security requirements, you have to invest in creating a container infrastructure with a server-side content authorization.

Comment: Well, the idea was to send out mail (from my app) without ahving it stored on the device sent items.. and wanted to know if there was a flag like 'noStore' or something which would prevent it from being stored. I dont need any user consent to not store a mail sent by my app. This question is not about gaining access to the sent items and deleting it.

Comment: @Ocelot Aha, but here is where you are incorrect: the mail was not sent from your app. You used a system service, and the system sent it using the user's mail provider. There's a big difference. If you had your own mailing system, that's OK. But if it's the user's system, it's a different story.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks.. So I assume that there's no possible way to tell the system not to store it.

Comment: What if the outgoing E-Mail was set to go to dummy@nowhere.com and the BCC was used for the real target?  Would the casual observer be able to see where the E-Mail went just by looking in the device's sent box?

Comment: @Gallymon It will still appear in the sent items folder.